# How to avoid VS assembly circular references in order to access DI container(Ninject)?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Imagine I have solution containing 2 class library projects : project1 exposes some interfaces, project2 exposes some interfaces and(!) consumes interfaces from project1. I have also project3 which sets up Ninject kernel module with all necessary interface bindigns. This looks like follows:

```
public class Dependencies : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFileSystemWatcherFactory>().To<FileSystemWatcherFactory>();
        Bind<IFileSystemWatcher>().To<FileSystemWatcher>();
        Bind( typeof( IRepository<> ) ).To( typeof( NHibernateRepository<> ) );
        Bind<IFileSystemHelper>().To<FileSystemHelper>();
        Bind<IFileSystemInfoAdapter>().To<FileSystemInfoAdapter>();
        Bind<IFolderMonitor>().To<FolderMonitor>();
        Bind<IFolderMonitorBrowser>().To<FolderMonitor>();
        Bind<IFileManager>().To<FileManager>();
    }
}

public class DiContainer
{
    private static IKernel _container;
    public static IKernel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _container == null )
                _container = new StandardKernel( new Dependencies() );

            return _container;
        }
    }

    private DiContainer() { }

}
```

In order to setup bindings, project3 needs reference to project1 and project2. In order to use DI container, project2 needs reference to project3 - but I cannot add it because VS shows error message that adding this reference would cause circular dependency.

How to deal with that problem ? Should I configure dependencies in XML ?

Comment: Does project 3 need to use the DI container - can't you inject its dependencies into it rather than getting it to resolve them itself? If you can't, it might make sense to move DiContainer into project1 since that's the glue that holds this all together. It might also make sense to move the project2 interfaces into project1 so that 3 doesn't need to depend on 2.

Answer (score 2):

If your project2 must reference your composit root in project3 then you are doing something wrong in there. Most likely you are doing

```
kernel.Get<ISomeDependency>()
```

The correct way is to use factories. Have a look at the Factory extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your interfaces to another assembly.

Dependency Inversion and Dependency Injection go well together but one *can* get entangled if you are not careful.

It'll just take some getting used to as to how you structure your projects.

**Edit**:

OK, may not be that simple :) but you should split out the relevant bits.  It will probably be easier to include your wiring in some infrastructure project that is part of your solution.  It need not be a separate project as it is closely related to your solution.